# Compatibility issue with my setup.exe which is made with InstallShield

Tags: installshield

I made a single executable file (setup.exe) using InstallShield 10.5.

The file size is around 3GB.

When I'm installing it shows a popup saying that "This program might not have been installed correctly".

What should I do?

Comment: check build parameters of install shield. does it allow you to choose target platform? for example, if you set a file header which tells OS it is made for windows XP, then future versions of windows would check the file and read that header and try to tell you about some compatibility settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just Windows way of asking you if you want any Compatibility Issues selected,
eg for a previous version of windows, or 'run as Admin', etc.

If you judge that it has not installed correctly, then Windows will try various options to put things right.

The gargantuan size of your setup file (what the heck are you thinking?) is most probably the cause!